# Nim source file which after it's normalized

Tags: nim-lang

How is the Nim capability to be able to produce its source file which has all been normalized, i.e. evaluated/expanded all of the directives, templates, macros, etc.with their same arguments ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, via `expandMacros`. https://nim-lang.org/docs/macros.html#expandMacros.m%2Ctyped

It's possible to implement your own `expandMacros` macro like this:

```
import macros

macro myExpandMacros(body: typed): typed =
  template inner(x: typed): typed = x

  result = getAst(inner(body))
  echo result.toStrLit
```

Usage example:

```
import macros, asyncdispatch

# Will echo expanded source code
# at compile time.
expandMacros:
  proc test() {.async.} =
    discard
```